# Unification validation in apps (backend .net & frontend)

Tags: .net, validation, design-patterns

I have a question for experienced developers: I have a little challenge finding a good solution for my current problem.

We have a very big .net 6 backend application and a React frontend application. We have validation of different things in different layers (domain, application, etc.) in the backend. Still, sometimes frontend developers make some validation in their application, so sometimes we have a situation where something in front has validation but not in the backend.

I want to stop this, and I am looking for some solution to the unification validation between us. Maybe you know something that can help me with this? Maybe there is an option to collect all validation in one place (something like an appsettings) and use it in the backend and share it with the front. Or maybe there are different options.

I believe that you know something interesting.

Comment: you can return from the backend all the validation result to the frontend. The frontend can skip its implementation of validation and add the errors on the form once it receives the 400 Bad Request response from the BE. there's no way to share code between .net and react

Comment: yes yes i know that there is no way to share code between them, but I thought about something like a meta-language, config file or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Below can be the ways to validate submitted inputs or data at one place for all client applications at server side:**

1. You can use Data Annotations in both .Net Framework and .Net Core using language like C# or VB.Net.
   **Example using C#:**

> **LoginRequestModel.cs**

```
public class LoginRequestModel
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Email Address is required")]
     [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]([-\\.\\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-][-\\w]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$", ErrorMessage = @"Email Address is invalid")]
     [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = @"More than 200 characters are not allowed for Email Address")]
     public string Username { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Password is required")]
     public string Password { get; set; }

     public bool Remember { get; set; }
}
```

> **ModelStateHelper.cs**

```
public static class ModelStateHelper
{
        public static dynamic GetValidationErrorsList(ActionContext actionContext)
        {
            dynamic response;

            response.Data = actionContext.ModelState
                    .Where(modelError => modelError.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .Select(modelError => new ValidationErrorsModel()
                    {
                        Field = modelError.Key.IndexOf('.') > -1 ? modelError.Key.Split('.')[1] : modelError.Key,
                        ErrorMessage = modelError.Value?.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.ErrorMessage
                    }).ToList();

            return response;
        }
}
```

> **LoginController.cs**

```
//Either we can handle data validations globally from Program.cs file or at specific action method.
//Here, I'm validating Login request parameters in action method
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("[action]")]
  public async Task<ResponseModel> Login(LoginRequestModel parameters)
  {
     //Here, we can simply add conditions to validate model/parameters data
     dynamic response = ModelStateHelper.GetValidationErrorsList(actionContext);
     if (response.Data != null)
         return response.Data;

     //Further code to proceed next steps in case when provided parameters are valid
  }
}
```

> **Output can be like below in case of validation failure:**

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "field": "Password",
      "errorMessage": "Password is required"
    },
    {
      "field": "Username",
      "errorMessage": "Email Address is invalid"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. You can also use NuGet package like [ASP.Net Core Fluent Validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html)

> ***Please note that this is just a brief example for explanation purpose only***